# To allow IPsec NAT-T traffic to pass through, why does the firewall still need to permit ESP when it already allows UDP 4500?

Tags: vpn, firewall, iptables, ipsec, nat-traversal

I established an IPsec VPN tunnel between two hosts across NAT, with the NAT being performed by the firewall (a Linux server). When attempting to configure the firewall rules to allow IPsec VPN traffic to pass through, I discovered that while IKE negotiation completes successfully with UDP ports 500 and 4500 allowed, VPN traffic communication does not function unless rules are added to allow ESP.

Here are the rules I applied on the firewall, but only IKE negotiation was completed:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Inbound
iptables -I FORWARD -s <External IP address> -d <Internal IP address> -p udp --sport 500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s <External IP address> -d <Internal IP address> -p udp --sport 4500 -j ACCEPT

# Outbound
iptables -I FORWARD -s <Internal IP address> -d <External IP address> -p udp --sport 4500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s <Internal IP address> -d <External IP address> -p udp --sport 500 -j ACCEPT
```

And the following two rules should also be set in order to successfully transmit data through the VPN tunnel:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s <External IP address> -d <Internal IP address> -p 50 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s <Internal IP address> -d <External IP address> -p 50 -j ACCEPT
```

Since the ESP data is encapsulated by the UDP header, why would the firewall block tunnel traffic without allowing ESP in rules? In my expectation, when the firewall sees that a packet contains a UDP port 4500 header, it should accept the packet accordingly.

Comment: ESP is not encapsulated in UDP, it runs directly over IP, as protocol #50 (UDP is protocol #17, TCP is #6). Also, it doesn't use port numbers, so port-mapping NAT doesn't really work with it. BTW, Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or networking; [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) is a better place for things like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson ESP can be encapsulated in UDP, but here it might not have been, otherwise, this wouldn't make sense (in particular in FORWARD). However, the UDP rules do not seem correct. It doesn't make sense to use `--sport` with those fixed ports for both directions because if a NAT is involved, the ports will most likely change on the NATed end.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the reminder, I will move this question to Superuser for posting.